# Error while passing external variable in an if condition in workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have a workflow containing 3 activities. The external variable that is used throughout the workflow is of type Dictionary which contains only two fields: EmailAddress and PhoneNumber(all strings). This is the screenshot of the workflow

[image]

So the scenario is that the activity GetParticipant has an outargument of type Dictionary which I am assigning to an external variable called **pax**. Using the if condition I am checking if the EmailAddress is provided or not.

My problem is that I am getting an error at the if condition:

```
Reference required to assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' containing the base class 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity'. Add one to your project.
```

The mentioned reference is already added to the project and the workflow also imports it. But the error remains. However giving only **True** as the condition works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Its seems some reference issue as i can see one bubble near if condition.
Check for dependency of mentioned Dll, can use nugget manager.
You can do below steps.

1. Delete reference of dll and import.
2. Clean solution and add reference and set property copy local true and import the namespace in workflow.
3. Rebuild the solution.